# Vocabolo italiano per "trading"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, translation, vocabulary

Qualcuno sa dirmi una parola italiana per "trading", inteso come compravendita/scambio di strumenti finanziari.

Per esempio, in espressioni come *trading platform*, *trading commissions*, e così via. Per dare una frase più completa a caso:

> John is trading cryptocurrencies on a Japanese exchange.

Anche la parola *exchange* mi lascia spesso in difficoltà, e la traduco semplicemente con piattaforma (online o meno).

Credo che oggi come oggi in italiano si possa usare tranquillamente la parola *trading* stessa. In ogni caso, anche se a volte può funzionare, in genere mi sembra "stonare", e comunque non sono un amante dell'usare selvaggiamente parole straniere a meno che non sia assolutamente necessario. Allo stesso tempo, *compravendita*, *negoziazione*, *scambio*, e tutte le altre parole che mi vengono in mente non mi sembrano adeguate.

Sarebbe anche utile avere una link a qualche glossario di terminologia finanziaria inglese-italiano (ad esempio che includa termini specifici come *margin trading*). Ho fatto un po' di ricerca ma non ho trovato molto. Grazie.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: Grazie @abarisone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [trading on line](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trading-on-line/) Treccani riporta:

> **trading on line** ‹*trèidiṅ òn làin*› locuz. ingl. (propr. «commerciare in
>   linea»), usata in ital. come s. m. – Nel linguaggio econ., attività di
>   negoziazione telematica di titoli di borsa.

Come vedi viene utilizzato il termine negoziazione, che è poi uno di quelli che avevi indicato, insieme a scambio e compravendita.

D’altronde anche il termine [trader](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trader/) compare nel dizionario Treccani:

> **trader** ‹*trèidë*› s. ingl. [der. di (*to*) *trade* «commerciare, scambiare»]
>   (pl. *traders* ‹*trèidë*∫›), usato in ital. al masch. e al femm. – Nel
>   linguaggio econ., chi negozia in modo regolare titoli di borsa, spec.
>   telematicamente.

per indicare chi negozia titoli in borsa.

Secondo me sono più che sufficienti i termini che hai indicato tu: negoziazione, compravendita, scambio.

Usare il termine commercio di titoli mi sembra un po’ troppo generale, anche se poi sarebbe quello più simile al significato originale inglese.

È a mio parere corretto cercare di usare termini italiani quando è possibile, ma in alcuni casi ormai alcune parole straniere sono entrate a far parte della nostra lingua, e vengono riportate nei vocabolari.

Io stesso preferisco fare riunioni piuttosto che meeting, compilazioni invece di build, corsi invece che training ma in alcuni ambiti la parola inglese sembra dia più autorevolezza a chi la pronuncia...

Comment: Anche io mi affido spesso alla Treccani, se è scritto là sicuramente si può usare tranquillamente. Sarà solo che cerco sempre dove possibile di non esagerare con termini stranieri quando ci sono valide alternative. Solo che certo, forse suona molto peggio "negoziazione di titoli" piuttosto che lasciare un semplice "trading". Grazie per la risposta.

Comment: io sono del parere che _compravendita_ o _negoziazione_ siano termini corretti da usare in questo caso.